# How to exclude all packages in directory from being published?

Tags: lerna

## Set up

I have a monorepository with a `./packages` directory, which contains packages I'll want Lerna to version & publish to NPM. I use Yarn with workspaces, and independent versioning.

I also have a `./integration-test` directory which contains integration tests that simulate importing packages from the `./packages` repository. They're for CI and should never be published to NPM.

## What I tried

I tried adding `"ignoreChanges": ["integration-test/**/*"]`, both in `lerna.json`'s root, and inside `command.publish` and `command.version`; but running `yarn lerna publish` or `yarn lerna changed -a` includes the package under `./integration-test`.

[`--ignore-changes` docs](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/version#--ignore-changes) say:

> In the following cases, a package will always be published, regardless of this option:
> The latest release of the package is a prerelease version (i.e. 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0–0.3.7, etc.).
> One or more linked dependencies of the package have changed.

I don't want to publish what's under `./integration-test` when their dependencies, packages they test that are under `./packages`, change.

I tried changing the package names of those under the `./integration-test` directory to be like `@foo/test.bar` and then in `lerna.json` add `"ignore": "\\@foo/test.*"`; but running `yarn lerna publish` or `yarn lerna changed -a` includes the package under `./integration-test`.

I tried changing the package names of those under the `./integration-test` directory to be like `@foo/test.bar` and then in `lerna.json` add `"scope": "\\@getbalance/!(integration-test.)*"`; but running `yarn lerna publish` or `yarn lerna changed -a` includes the package under `./integration-test`.

---

**How do I properly configure Lerna to never publish what's under the `./integration-test` directory?**

Comment: Deleting the `"version"` entry from `package.json`s under `./integration-test` makes Lerna stop wanting to publish them, but also chokes Yarn.

Comment: Workaround: delete all `package.json`s under `./integration-test` and figure out another mechanism for resolving dependencies/paths that isn't npm.

Answer (score 3):

The `ignoreChanges` will ignore file changes when running `lerna version` but as the docs said, it won't stop from publishing that package. The ignore is just useful when you use the conventional changelog option and you don't want certain files (like readme.md, ...) to bump a version, for example if you just released a new version and then you commit a simple typo fix in a readme.md file, if you run the `lerna version` without the ignore configured, it will try to bump a patch version, however if you have Lerna configured to ignore "readme.md" changes and you run `lerna version`, it will say "No commits in this repository. Please commit something before using version."

Alright so the first paragraph was just giving you an explanation of the ignore option, but it was not very helpful to fix your problem. I would imagine that the problem you're facing is caused by the use of Yarn and you probably also have the `userWorkspace: true` (in `lerna.json`) and `workspaces` (in `package.json`) that includes the integration folder and that's why it's being published. If that is the case, then I would disable `useWorkspace: false` and instead configure and use `"packages"` (in `lerna.json`) to only include `packages/*`, if we summarize that in code, we will have the following:

```json
# lerna.json
{ 
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "useWorkspace": false,
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

```json
# package.json
{
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "integration-test/*",
      "packages/*"
    ],
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

In summary, if `useWorkspace` is enabled, it will use whatever is in "workspaces" in your `package.json` but if you disable it, it will use `"packages"` from your `lerna.json`

**Note** the latest version of Lerna >=5.3.0 seems to be blocking users from applying this technique. I might be wrong, but I think they automatically use the `workspaces` when it is detected in the `package.json`. If that's the case, you can use [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/ghiscoding/lerna-lite) as alternative, that I support, which doesn't block you from doing this technique that I mentioned of favoring the `"packages"` in `lerna.json`. The [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) project is configured this way and also uses Lerna-Lite (please note that Lerna-Lite assumes `useWorkspace` as false when it's not provided in `lerna.json`, so you can omit it, but I think newer Lerna will auto-detect it and enable it which is why I recommend Lerna-Lite in this use case)